# GCC not warning on implicit cast from void * to void **

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, warnings, void-pointers

As void * is the generic pointer, any other type can be implicitly cast to it. However, void ** isn't the generic pointer to pointer thus I would expect a warning from gcc if I implicitly cast to it.

In my code I have a function that takes a pointer to an opaque pointer (because it can be realloced and written back) as:

```
char *string_store(void **ctxp, const char *str);
```

If I call this incorrectly as:

```
void *context;
...
name = string_store(content, "my name");
```

instead of `string_store(&content...)`, I would expect gcc to warn about this. But it doesn't. I have -Wall -Wextra options to gcc.

Is there a warning option to turn this on? I can't find it in the gcc docs.

Comment: I guess I meant the question to read: "to void ** from void *"

Comment: You can edit your own question's title and content. :)

Comment: Oh - I forgot that. Seems right anyway. Maybe my mind is going.....:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As void * is the generic pointer, any other type can be implicitly cast to it.

You are right that `void *` is the generic pointer. This means *two* things:

- Any other pointer type is implicitly cast to `void *`;
- `void *` is implicitly cast to any other pointer type.

The lack of warning by GCC, therefore, is not because you are implicitly casting *to* `void **`, but because you are implicitly casting *from* `void *`. A warning, as you request, would be inappropriate in many cases, including this very real use case:

```
void **ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
```

As such, I don't believe that it is even desirable. For stricter pointer conversions, use C++, where most implicit `void *` casts have been removed.

There is, apparently, the `-Wc++-compat` flag which will warn about this, but you may get very annoyed by it.

> Warn about ISO C constructs that are outside of the common subset of ISO C and ISO C++, e.g. request for implicit conversion from void * to a pointer to non-void type.

Comment: Doh! You're absolutely right. "From void *" not "to void **". Thank you! (I'm feeling a bit dim now for not having seen that!).